# Error with sending email

Tags: php, email, smtp

I got problem in email send. When i use domain email in my php script i got mail but when i use gmail it not send and it show error.

Here is code (http://pastebin.com/XTCB3mch):

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
        return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
        exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
        exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
        exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
        exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have entered an invalid e-mail address. Please try again.</div>';
        exit();
}

if(trim($subject) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a subject.</div>';
        exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
        exit();
} else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
        exit();
} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
        exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@example.net";
$address = "mdali_siddique@yahoo.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You have been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: ali@uparrowconsulting.com" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

        // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

        echo "<fieldset>";
        echo "<div id='success_page'>";
        echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
        echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

        echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

In line number 81: `$headers = “From: ali@uparrowconsulting.com” . PHP_EOL;`

When i change it to gmail id it show error. What is the solution.

I also try PHPmailer Here is code (http://pastebin.com/BaDVLxch):

```
<?php

$name= $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email= $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$comments= $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

require("/home/uparw/public_html/demo6/14/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer;

// For Useing Domian mail
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Host = 'localhost';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'ali@uparw.com';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

// For Gmail
//$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
//$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
//$mail->IsHTML(true);
//$mail->Username = "aliuparrow@gmail.com";
//$mail->Password = "password";


$mail->From = 'ali@uparw.com';
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->addAddress('alisiddique2011@gmail.com', 'Ali Siddique');  // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('alisiddique2011@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('alisiddique2011@gmail.com', 'Ali');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Query From healthjourney ';
$mail->Body    = 'Email: ' . $email . '<br />' . 'Comment: ' . $comments;
$mail->AltBody = 'Email: ' . $email . '<br />' . 'Comment: ' . $comments;

//if(!$mail->send()) {
   //echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  // exit;
//}
  $output = '';
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       $output .= "Mailer Error: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
       ob_clean();
       header('Location: thankyou.html');
       exit();
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Line number 30: `$mail->From = ‘ali@uparw.com’;`

Same Problem is here also. If I change it gmail or other ac mail not sending. But if i use domain mail mail sending well.

Need Some Help.

Comment: Please show your code here, not just a link to pastebin.com. Try to distill it down to a SSCCE.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sure it's not going into the junk/spam folder of the recipient?

Comment: i think you must do some configuaration in smtp settings, and in php.ini

Comment: Perhaps gmail requires SMTP authentication? I mean.. Try adding this: $mail->IsSMTP(); (in your gmail area, in the other one you setted it. Also, try adding this too: $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = "true";

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send email using your GMail account then you will need to use SMTP. Please check the following link for more details

http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server

If all your details are correct and you are doing everything as suggested in the above link then your email should be sent out